# How to login on a Domino server with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, lotus-domino, angularjs-http

I'd like to login to a Domino server from an angularjs webpage. The page itself resides in the database I want to authenticate with, so it's not really remote.
This is my code:

```
return $http({
                url: 'http://servername/names.nsf?login',
                data: {
                    'username': 'myusername',
                    'password': 'whateverpassword',
                    'redirectto': '/path_to_db.nsf/$icon'
                },
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                }
            })
            .then(loginComplete)
            .catch(loginFailed);
```

What I get in return is a HTTP response 200. When I do a manual login I get a HTTP 302 and a DomAuthSessId cookie. So the request behaves differently. When I do the post, there is a SessionID cookie available, so there should be a session with the server. Any ideas about what I'm forgetting here? Thanks in advance!

Maybe I should outline what I'm trying to achieve too:

1. Get a username and password from a different source
2. Use them to login and get a session with the Domino server without being prompted.

Ultimately we will use SAML for single sign-on, but we're still on Domino 8.5.3, so this is not an option for now.

Answer (score 0):

Martin, how about the ACL if the Angular page is in the NSF?

I am using a Domino datasbase with an Angular UI - no XPages at all (well apart from a launcher to \index.html).  The ACL forces you to logon when opening the NSF, thus when the Angular page opens you are authenticated.

Could you do this until you upgrade to Domino 9 and use SAML?

Comment: Key is: I don't want the user to manually authenticate. There's a batch reader involved, who gives me the username, and from there on I want to authenticate automatically with the server.